# Popup window on clicking GirdView Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, popupwindow

My Question is that When I click on a cell of Gridview then a Popup Window should be displayed where I could perform CRUD operations. Anyone, please Help me. Thank you!

Comment: WPF? WinForms? could you post what you have and what you've tried?  It seems to me your missing some information we'll need to help you.

Comment: I need the Solution in Web Forms. I have tried a lot but I failed. The scenario is that. When i click on the column of a gridview then a popup should be show where i can perform CRUD operations. Popup can be in jquery, bootstrap or in any other form. Please Help me. I need urgent

Answer (score 0):

View :

```
 <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Column Modification">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Click="Button_Click_Modification" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```

Model:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //PopupWindow
}
```

Comment: Compliments on the quality of your first answer! However I think OP is using webforms, not winforms or wpf. Although the question itself is quite terrible.

Comment: Yes,  I am using Webforms.